# npm uninstall doesn't delete file

Tags: node.js, npm, uninstallation

I am new to nodejs and npm and I am trying to understand how `npm uninstall` works.

I have downloaded and installed a module, messed around a bit with its code, but now I want to restore the original version, so I did:

`npm uninstall <module>`

(no more  folder in my node_modules folder)

`npm install <module>`

but after the installation the files that are back are the one I have precedent modified and not the original one (even if I see all the `GET` message from `npm` while I install)

I tried also `npm uninstall --save <module>`, and `npm cache clean`,  but with the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` to empty npm's cache before installing.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating npm, uninstalling the module, cleaning the cache with -f, and then reinstalling it again finally worked!